# Iterating through files gives odd results when no files

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to iterate through all zip files in a bash script (I'm using Cygwin, but I kind of doubt this is a bug with Cygwin).

It looks like this right now:

```
for z in *.zip
do
    echo $z
done
```

which works well when there are zip files in the folder, and it echos exactly the zip files and nothing but the zip files. However, when I do it on a folder that's empty, it echos `*.zip`, when I'd rather it echo nothing.

What should I be doing? I don't think the right solution is `if [ $z != "*.zip ]`... but is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

> If no matching filenames are found, and the shell option `nullglob` is disabled, the word is left unchanged. If the `nullglob` option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.

So the solution is to set the `nullglob` option before the loop:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for z in *.zip
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

As one of its steps for executing a command, the shell may perform *path expansion* in which case it will replace a string, such as `*.zip` with the list of files that match that glob.  *If there are no such files, then the string is left unchanged.*  A reasonable solution is:

```
for z in *.zip
do
    [ -f "$z" ] && echo $z
done
```

`[ -f "$z" ]` verifies that the file exists and is a regular file.  The `&&` means that `echo` will be executed only if that test is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Either that or turning on the [`nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) option.

```
$ set -x
$ echo *.none
+ echo '*.none'
*.none
$ shopt -s nullglob
+ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo *.none
$ echo *.none
+ echo
```